# Selenium/Webdriver/Java: How to verify that particular elements scrollbar was scrolled down to bottom?

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver, scrollbar

Maybe somebody has a clue how to verify if particular elements scroll bar was scrolled down to bottom?
I use Selenium and Webdriver on Java (running JUnit scripts).

Can't figure how to do that at all... Thanks. :)

Comment: post some html-code sample please.

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample code, it would just be guesses. If it's a container div and contains more elements inside, you may want to use any element located at the bottom to check if its visible.